# Determine which UITextView UIDataDetectorType was triggered

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using `UITextView`'s delegate method `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:interaction:` to catch the URL taps. Is there any way to determine which `UIDataDetectorTypes` triggered the delegate method?

I have different custom methods for emails, phone numbers, addresses (geographical), date/time, etc. Right now the only method I can see is to use RegEx to "guess" the type from a combination of using the URL (which is pretty useless for anything than http/https urls) and the raw data that is tapped on via

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange interaction:(UITextItemInteraction)interaction {
    NSString *rawText = [textView.text substringWithRange:characterRange];
    // Do fancy stuff with the data

    // Hacky way to test if the url tapped isn't an email/map address
    BOOL isURL = [[URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:[textView.text substringWithRange:characterRange]];

    // Return no when the URL can be captured and custom methods used. Otherwise return YES.
    return NO;
}
```

EDIT: I have stumbled across `NSDataDetector` which may help but I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution to my issue. I'm posting my answer so that any else struggling with this issue can see what I did (and potentially help improve my code if it is not great).

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange interaction:(UITextItemInteraction)interaction {
    NSString *string = [textView.text substringWithRange:characterRange];
    if (string.length <= 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    NSError *dataDetectorError = nil;
    NSTextCheckingTypes dataCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeDate | NSTextCheckingTypeAddress | NSTextCheckingTypeLink | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber;
    NSDataDetector *dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:dataCheckingTypes error:&dataDetectorError];
    if (!isNull(dataDetectorError)) {
        NSLog(@"Data detector init error: %@", dataDetectorError.localizedDescription);
        return YES;
    }

    [dataDetector enumerateMatchesInString:string
                                   options:kNilOptions
                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
                                usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                                    if (!isNull(result)) {
                                        // Now we get the result type
                                        switch (result.resultType) {
                                            case NSTextCheckingTypeDate:
                                            case NSTextCheckingTypeAddress:
                                            case NSTextCheckingTypeLink:
                                                if([result.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"mailto:"].location != NSNotFound) {
                                                    // email
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    // url
                                                }
                                            case NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber:
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                // Ignore all other types
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
     ];
}
```

Obviously it's an incomplete implementation however it shows how to use the built in RegEx subclass to get the different types